# How can I have systemd execute a script only if a service was stopped via systemctl, but not execute if it crashed by itself?

Tags: linux, systemd, upstart

What I am looking for, is the equivalent of the pre-stop stanza in upstart, for systemd

Answer (score 1):

You can use one or more `ExecStop=` directives to add systemd-specific stop commands. See `man systemd.service` for details.

Comment: ExecStop= directives are not exactly equivalent to pre-stop stanzas because pre-stop does not get executed when service crashes, whereas ExecStop= is executed regardless of whether the service crashed due to a failure, or was stopped through systemctl

Comment: @Abhay the man for systemd ExecStop claims "Note that the commands specified in ExecStop= are only executed when the service started successfully first. They are not invoked if the service was never started at all, or in case its start-up failed, for example because any of the commands specified in ExecStart=, ExecStartPre= or ExecStartPost= failed (and weren't prefixed with "-") or timed out." ~ https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Note that it isn't called if startup failed.